# About "group function is not allowed here"

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-delete

I have a table with job, salary and date columns. I am writing the following query in PL/SQL, but I am getting an error

> group function is not allowed here

```
delete employees where date = '06-05-2020 'and avg (salary)> 5500;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query makes no sense (to me, at least). What does that *average salary* represent? *Whose* average salary?

Here's an example based on Scott's `EMP` table; I'm going to delete employees who were hired on 3th of December 1981 and work in department whose employees' average salary is higher than 2000.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, sal, hiredate from emp order by deptno, ename;

    DEPTNO ENAME             SAL HIREDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        20 ADAMS            1100 12.01.1983
        20 FORD             3000 03.12.1981   --> this
        20 JONES            2975 02.04.1981
        20 SCOTT            3000 09.12.1982
        20 SMITH             800 17.12.1980
        30 ALLEN            1600 20.02.1981
        30 BLAKE            2850 01.05.1981
        30 JAMES             950 03.12.1981   --> this
        30 MARTIN           1250 28.09.1981
        30 TURNER           1500 08.09.1981
        30 WARD             1250 22.02.1981

11 rows selected.
```

Averege salaries per department:

```
SQL> select deptno, avg(sal) avg_salary
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno
  4  order by avg_salary desc;

    DEPTNO AVG_SALARY
---------- ----------
        20       2175         --> higher than 2000
        30 1566,66667
```

So: I'm looking for employees who work in department **20** (as only that department has average salaries higher than 2000) and who were hired on 03.12.1981 (James and Ford, but only **Ford** works in department 20):

```
SQL> delete from emp
  2  where hiredate = date '1981-12-03'
  3    and deptno in (select deptno
  4                   from emp
  5                   group by deptno
  6                   having avg(sal) > 2000
  7                  );

1 row deleted.
```

Is Ford still in there?

```
SQL> select * From emp where ename = 'FORD';

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Nope, deleted.

---

Now, your turn.